# Error when using Reflections in Java

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I'm having a casting issue in this code but have no idea how to correct it.

```
public void showFrame(String className, Object controller) throws Exception{
    try {
       Class c = Class.forName("com." + className);
       // "(Object.class)" I want this to be of type held in className var
       // this type will be same as one passed into  "controller" at runtime
       Constructor ctr = c.getConstructor(Object.class);  
       ctr.newInstance(controller);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error" );
    }
}
```

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Please provide a complete but minimal example including a) an example class containing the constructor b) the actual call to `showFrame` for this class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getConstructor` selects from the possible existing constructors for the class in question.

If your class name looks like:

```
com.mycorp.SomeClass
```

and it doesn't have a

```
public SomeClass(Object object) {
  ...
}
```

constructor, then `ctr` will be null.  If it does have such a constructor, then asking for a new instance without providing a value for the `Object` parameter is just asking for trouble.

In addition, you are only catching if the class doesn't exist, not of the constructor can't be found, or if the security manager denies new class creation, or if the constructor is getting called with the wrong number of parameters, etc.